# Cannot ping Ubuntu server with configured public IP address

Tags: networking, server

I setup a new server in our office (Ubuntu 16.04) and configured it with 2 interfaces, 1 for internal (192.168.x.x) and the other is configured with public IP (123.123.123.1)

curl ifconfig.co shows my configured public IP. However, i cannot ping my machine from the outside but the machine can send traffic to the internet. Ping from inside the network can ping the private IP, but not the public IP also.

Firewall already disabled (ufw disable)

Any idea?

PS. Linux noob btw

Comment: Looks like better to ask it on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Can you access the internet via the internal network (192.168.x.x)? If yes, disconnect this interface and make sure your server can access the internet.

Comment: my server can access the internet since i set my ISP as the gateway. traceroute shows that my server's next hop was the ISP. BUt from inside my network, i cannot ping the configured public IP of my server, neither SSH. but i can SSH using the private IP.

Comment: to check if really no firewall rule is applying type 'sudo iptables -L' Policy Rule should be accept and no other rules should be listed (very insecure setup). How is your server connected physically to the internet? Is the cable directly connected from your computer to a modem or is there any router in between? If there is a router in between you need to setup portforwarding in that device.